# Is there a "Mouse Mirror" mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I love Synergy, its GREAT, but there is one bit of functionality that I think it is missing, and I wondered if it is possible to do this.

I would like to be able to have the mouse movements appear SIMULTANEOUSLY on all screens.

So, if I have 1 Server and 4 clients, and I move the mouse UP, the mouse moves up on all 5 of the screens. Is this possible?

This functionality would be GREAT in education, where all computers are set up the same, so that I could show students how to operate software on their own machines rather than looking at a projector.

Is this possible or is there other software to do it?

Comment: When I was in high school, the teacher can share her screen to display on our screen, we cannot do anything on the computer until she release the lock.

Answer (score 1):

I think any type of solution that blindly mimics mouse movements only would be flacky because some student might have other windows open that block the way to the actual window that you want to click, or their initial mouse positions would be different.

The projector is probably your best bet or if you prefer it to be on the student's monitor, there are webinar software that displays your screen to other computers that choose to connect to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is software specifically designed for this purpose, called "Classroom Management" software.  There is a popular free open source package called iTALC.

http://italc.sourceforge.net/

There is a review here:

http://www.classroom20.com/forum/topics/649749:Topic:66371

List of features (from the website):

> iTALC has been designed for usage in school. Therefore it offers a lot of possibilities to teachers, such as
>
> - see what's going on in computer-labs by using overview mode and make snapshots
> - **remote-control computers** to support and help other people
> - **show a demo** (either in fullscreen or in a window) - the teacher's screen is shown on all student's computers in realtime
> - **lock workstations** for moving undivided attention to teacher
> - send **text-messages** to students
> - **powering on/off** and rebooting computers per remote
> - remote logon and logoff and remote execution of arbitrary commands/scripts
> - **home-schooling** - iTALC's network-technology is not restricted to a subnet and therefore students at home can join lessons via VPN-connections just by installing iTALC client
>
> Furthermore iTALC is optimized for usage on multi-core systems (by making heavy use of threads). No matter how many cores you have, iTALC can make use of all of them

[image: screenshot of iTALC]